# How to merge 2 array objects with different key's name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to merge `obj1` and `obj2` if they share the same role id.

if `obj1.roleId` is equal to `obj2.id`

```
this.state = {
  obj1: [{
    "firstName": "Sally",
    "id": 2635,
    "roleId": 1
  }, {
    "firstName": "Dylan",
    "id": 2636,
    "roleId": 2
  }, {
    "firstName": "Tom",
    "id": 2637,
    "roleId": 3
  }],
  obj2: [{
    "name": "Supervisor",
    "id": 2,
  }, {
    "name": "Developer",
    "id": 1,
  }, {
    "name": "Quality Assurance",
    "id": 3,
  }]
}
```

into something like this, where I can rename the key's name from `obj2`:

```
obj3: [{
    "firstName": "Sally",
    "id": 2635,
    "roleId": 1,
    "roleName": "Developer",
  }, {
    "firstName": "Dylan",
    "id": 2636,
    "roleId": 2,
    "roleName": "Supervisor",
  }, ...]
```

Please give me a hand if possible.
Many thanks.

Comment: rearrange obj2 so it's an object with properties 1,2,3 that have values Supervisor, etc - the rest writes itself

Comment: Thanks @Bravo, but what if I didn't know obj2's order

Comment: huh? nothing to do with order

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var obj3 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < state.obj1.length; i++){
  for(var p = 0; p < state.obj2.length; p++){
    if(state.obj1[i].roleId == state.obj2[p].id){
      obj3.push({"firstName": state.obj1[i].firstName,
      "id": state.obj1[i].id,
      "roleId": state.obj1[i].roleId,
      "roleName": state.obj2[p].name})
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj3);
```

Answer (score 1):

create a temporary object from obj2 - property names `id` with value `name`

Then a simple map to copy from obj1 adding the roleName from the above

```js
const state = {
  obj1: [{
    "firstName": "Sally",
    "id": 2635,
    "roleId": 1
  }, {
    "firstName": "Dylan",
    "id": 2636,
    "roleId": 2
  }, {
    "firstName": "Tom",
    "id": 2637,
    "roleId": 3
  }],
  obj2: [{
    "name": "Supervisor",
    "id": 2,
  }, {
    "name": "Developer",
    "id": 1,
  }, {
    "name": "Quality Assurance",
    "id": 3,
  }]
};
const t = Object.fromEntries(state.obj2.map(({name, id}) => [id, name]))
state.obj3 = state.obj1.map(v=>({...v,roleName:t[v.roleId]}));

console.log(state.obj3)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate the two objects, and merge them

```js
objects.obj1.forEach(o1 => {
  objects.obj2.forEach(o2 => {
    if (o1.roleId === o2.id) {
      result.push({...o1, name: o2.name})
    }
  })
})
```

```js
const objects = {
  obj1: [{
    "firstName": "Sally",
    "id": 2635,
    "roleId": 1
  }, {
    "firstName": "Dylan",
    "id": 2636,
    "roleId": 2
  }, {
    "firstName": "Tom",
    "id": 2637,
    "roleId": 3
  }],
  obj2: [{
    "name": "Supervisor",
    "id": 2,
  }, {
    "name": "Developer",
    "id": 1,
  }, {
    "name": "Quality Assurance",
    "id": 3,
  }]
}

const result = []

objects.obj1.forEach(o1 => {
  objects.obj2.forEach(o2 => {
    if (o1.roleId === o2.id) {
      result.push({...o1, name: o2.name})
    }
  })
})

console.log(result)
```